# WebView not showing my html file

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a webView in my ViewController. I have created a BullsEye.html file in my project and I want to show that html file in my web view. Following is my code

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "BullsEye",
                                 withExtension: "html") {
      if let htmlData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        let baseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath)
        webView.load(htmlData, mimeType: "text/html",
                     textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: baseURL)
      }
    }
```

The above code is written in viewDidLoad. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your source code itself, I think.

But maybe does `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "BullsEye", withExtension: "html")` return nil?
If so, you should check for the two things below:

1. Whether the file to be read is included in Copy Bundle Resources

   Files to be included in the project are registered in `TARGETS> Build Phases> Copy Bundle Resources`.

[image]

2. Whether the file to be read exists in the project directory

   Open the project directory in the Finder and check if the file you are trying to load actually exists.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Bounty will be awarded in 5 hours. The file was missing in Copy Bundle Resources

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code as is and was able to make things work as seen here after changing the webView loader code. This tells me you likely have a UIWebView lurking somewhere, likely your view in storyboard.

[image]

I would recommend you make sure that you are consistently using WKWebView throughout:

- Import `WebKit` in your class file
- Have a valid output link to it if you are using a storyboard
- If using a storyboard, ensure that you are using `WKWebView` and not the deprecated **UIWebView**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Kazunori's answer was correct. Appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you.

```
   func loadHtmlFile() {
        if let fileurl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "BullsEye", withExtension: "html") {  
            let request = URLRequest(url: fileurl!)
            webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

See - [swiftdeveloperblog](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/load-html-file-into-uiwebview-programmatically/)

Also if the code don't seem to work for you, make sure to open html file in any browser and check if it's a valid html file.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. I opened my html file in a browser and it works perfectly

Comment: What log messages do you get while trying to load?

Comment: I tried your code also, I get the same log 2018-05-16 21:29:25.923316+0530 BullsEye[775:45287] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-05-16 21:29:25.924595+0530 BullsEye[775:45287] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework